# Process substitution issue in GDB's shell

Tags: bash, gdb

The following code, **readTwice.c**, reads twice from standard input:

```
int main()
{
    char s[8]={0};
    read(0, (void *)s, (size_t) 3);
    read(0, (void *)(s + 4), (size_t) 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        printf("%d: 0x%x\n", i, s[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

My objective is to, while debugging the corresponding binary, feed the first read() with a first file **a** (say, created by `echo a > a`), and the second read() with a second file **b** (say, created by `echo b > b`).

Outside GDB, the following bash 5.0 command has the desired effect:

```
$ ./readTwice < <(cat a;cat b)
0: 0x61
1: 0xa
2: 0x0
3: 0x0
4: 0x62
5: 0xa
6: 0x0
7: 0x0
```

However, when running the binary in GDB 8.2.1 with the same process redirection, the first read() call also reads the beginning of the second file:

```
$ gdb -q readTwice
Reading symbols from readTwice...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) run < <(cat a;cat b)
Starting program: /home/av/root-me/ch77/readTwice < <(cat a;cat b)
0: 0x61
1: 0xa
2: 0x62
3: 0x0
4: 0xa
5: 0x0
6: 0x0
7: 0x0
[Inferior 1 (process 4710) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

Could you help me understand this behaviour and/or tell me about a command having the desired effect ?

Comment: Both outputs are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input to your program consists of 4 characters:

```
'a' '\n' 'b' '\n'
```

Inside your program you use two `reads`:

```
read(0, (void *)s, (size_t) 3);
read(0, (void *)(s + 4), (size_t) 3);
```

`read` doesn't read *exactly* `3` characters. It reads up to `3` characters and returns the number of characters read, see [man read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html). I assume by default `STDIN_FILENO` is blocking on your platform, so it should read at least 1 character.

Possible outcomes:

- Both `read`s read 1 byte. `s` will have `{'a',0,0,0,'\n',0,0,0}`. There are `2` unread bytes in the input.
- First `read` read 1 byte, second reads 3 bytes. `s` will have `{'a',0,0,0,'\n','b','\n',0}`
- First `read` reads 3 bytes, second reads 1 byte. `s` will have `{'a','\n','b',0,'\n',0,0,0}`. This is the output you observe in `gdb`.
- First `read` reads 2 bytes, second reads 2 bytes. `s` will have `{'a','\n',0,0,'b','\n',0,0}`. This is the output you observe when running in shell.
- Hopefully you get the idea by now.

Most probably your operating system implements `read` on `STDIN_FILENO` in a line buffered fashion on your platform, so the two most possible outcomes are the ones you are observing.

Comment: Yes, on my platform STDIN_FILENO (which equals 0 there) is blocking. If I understand your explanation: when the first read() reads the temporary named pipe created by the process substitution  `<(cat a;cat b)`, 1 <= i <= 4 bytes are read from the pipe where i depends on the relative speeds of processes ./readTwice and (cat a;cat b).

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for the second part of my question ?

Comment: `1 <= i <= 4` no, it's `<= 3`, you passed 3 as max, not 4. `i depends on the relative speeds` - well, yes, there is a race condition between the writing and reading sides. `Do you ... ?` - what is a second part of you question? How to make it right? Read exactly two characters the first time, if you read 1 char, repeat the read.

Comment: Yes ofc i <= 3 my bad. My second part of the question was not clear enough, let me clarify: `readTwice` is a toy model for a binary (which makes two analogous read() calls from standard input) that I can't modify and that I want to debug, I want to find a command inside GDB to feed exactly some file *a* (resp. *b) to the first (resp. second) read() call.

Comment: The best solution would be to link the library with your custom `read` implementation. Then you can do exactly what you want. A semi-good solution would be to write a C program that opens a pipe to stdin of this program. Reads and writes on pipes less then PIPE_BUF are atomic, so write 2 bytes, wait (or maybe POLLOUT?), write 2 bytes, wait. A very bad solution would be `<(cat a; sleep 1; cat b)`.